# how to set planner for cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to set a planner to profile a cypher query, and I'm getting an error (not a clear one)

the beginning of the query:

```
PROFILE
PLANNER RULE
MATCH....
```

the error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper syntax to select the [planner](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#how-are-queries-executed) is

```
 CYPHER planner=rule ...
```

Combined with `PROFILE`, you should use:

```
PROFILE CYPHER planner=rule ...
```

Comment: thanks so much @frank-pavageau!
maybe you can answer this question as well :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750887/setting-cypher-planner-for-a-query