# setting cypher planner for a query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to understand cypher planner, and I'm not sure of few things.

1. should I ever change it, or let the Cypher engine to control it?
2. what is the difference between the COST and the RULE planner?

Answer (score 1):

1. Since every version of neo4j may tweak the planners, the only way to know for sure which planner works better for a specific query and a specific neo4j version would be to use `PROFILE` and performance testing. Also, since the plan generated by the COST planner depends on the actual characteristics of your data, you may also want to periodically test query performance with both planners even when you do not upgrade to a newer neo4j version.
2. [This neo4j blog entry](https://neo4j.com/blog/tuning-cypher-queries/) provides some details on the planners.